# aws-ses gem and mass emailing: do I call once with array of 1000 addresses, or loop 1000 times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services

I have SES setup and am preparing my app to send out mass emailings of 600 - 1000 addresses per mailing.

I would like to know if I should call the send method once with 1000 emails, or call the send 1000 times with one email each.

Also, I'm on Heroku, with a 30 second execution time.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you sending these messages out?

Comment: I'm using aws-ses gem. It's quite nice, except for a bcc bug (they are ignored).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing anything remotely intensive as sending 1000 emails in a web response. I suggest using the [Delayed Job](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job) gem. It will run the processes in the background by scaling a worker and turning it off when it's done. Since workers are charged per minute, you'll have at most a couple cents per month to pay since your task should be done in less than a minute and shouldn't run all that often. You also won't have to worry about the 30 second execution time.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I guess I was trying to avoid any fees. I didn't know about the delayed job gem, which seems that it will seriously reduce those fees. Thanks for the response!

Comment: The article you link to forces you to start and stop workers manually. That is pretty disappointing. Is there not a programatic way to start / stop workers?

Comment: Oh yeah my bad I forgot to give you the autoscaling fork: https://github.com/pedro/delayed_job/tree/autoscaling